# Displaying "[et_pb_section fb_built="1" cus..." instead of page using Divi Builder

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a site on wordpress, but I edit the site on DIVI. But Divi Builder for some reason at one point began to show some code instead of the page.

How to fix it? I would be very grateful for your help.
[image]
Plugins:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Divi theme or Divi Builder plugin? If none of them are activated then also it will show shortcodes instead of builder.

If you are using Divi theme, then try enabling Safe Mode Option.

**Make sure to take backup of files and database before performing this.**

To enable Safe Mode, Go to Divi > Support Center > Safe Mode. You will see toggle button.

Once Safe Mode is enabled, try to reload the page where divi builder is not loaded. If Divi builder is loading in Safe mode then it must be any plugin causing the issue. If still not then try to contact Divi support team.

You can also try options given in [this article](https://diviengine.com/7-things-to-try-when-the-divi-builder-is-not-loading/).